# Стирание с Javascript или PHP

Tags: php, html, javascript

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы в Javascript или PHP текст набирался и заменялся.
Есть цикл(например Javascript)

```
for (a = 1; a<5;a++){}
```

Надо чтобы выводилась 1, потом 1 поменялось на 2, 2 поменялась на 3, а 3 поменялась на 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="qwe">
</div>

var qwe = document.getElementById('qwe');
for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    (function(){
        var p = i;
        setTimeout(function(){
                qwe.innerHTML = p;
        }, 1000 * i);
    })();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="count">0</div>
<script>
function TPPPPPblHb(el, stop){
    var a = el.innerHTML = ~~el.innerHTML + 1;
    if(a < stop) setTimeout(function(){
        TPPPPPblHb(el, stop);
    }, 1000);
}
TPPPPPblHb(document.getElementById('count'), 5);
</script>
```

Есть пара нюансов, связанных с этим кодом. Но вы их без труда найдете сами). сам код рабочий.

Answer (score 1):

К примеру на странице есть

```
<div id='my-div'></div>
```

Тогда этот скрипт запустит в нем таймер

```
    var i = 0;

    function timer(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            action();
            timer(i);
        }, 1000);
    }

    function action() {
        i++;
        document.getElementById('my-div').innerHTML = i;
    }

    timer(1000);
```

Динамически изменять контент на странице, не перезагружая саму страницу при этом, можно только javascriptom.

Надеюсь помог, gl :3

Comment: Будет такой прикольный трррррынь - и 100 в диве.

Comment: точняк) поправил скрипт)